# Using a Node packages with Electron return me an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Tags: node.js, json, api, npm, electron

So i'm trying to make an app like a pokedex with electron, for making this i need to use [this api](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokedex-promise-v2) witch is the node version of [this one](https://pokeapi.co).

My problem is when i try to use the api my console just return me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` :

```
// basic setup
var Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2');
var options = {
  protocol: 'https',
  hostName: 'localhost:443',
  versionPath: '/api/v2/',
  cacheLimit: 100 * 1000, // 100s
  timeout: 5 * 1000 // 5s
}
var P = new Pokedex(options);

// get a berry by name
P.getBerryByName('cheri')
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There was an ERROR: ', error);
});
```

And here is what my console return me :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
base.js:26 There was an ERROR:  Error: Network Error
    at createError (D:\Documents\_Dev\Pokecheck\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (D:\Documents\_Dev\Pokecheck\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:87)
```

I've also tried to use a url to a json file (ex: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/) but it complitely break my app when a integrate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = {
  protocol: 'https',
  hostName: 'pokeapi.co',
  versionPath: '/api/v2/',
  cacheLimit: 100 * 1000, // 100s
  timeout: 5 * 1000 // 5s
}
```

I assume you're not running the API on your local machine. So asking localhost on something that is not running will result in a **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

The Pokedex has a default option if you don't parse the option object, that one is already set up how you'll need it.

So basically you just need `var P = new Pokedex();` without the option.